# How to index with colon in c#

Tags: c#, indexing

I want to access an instance of the class with the syntax like `A[:,2]` which is quite widespread among programming languages.

Assume, I have some class `ClassA` with a 2-dimensional double array in its property `Content` and created an instance A of it.

If I want to access `A.Content[2,3]` by `A[2,3]`, I need to build inside the ClassA this method:

```
public double this[int i, int j]
{
    get
    {
        return this.Content[i,j];
    }
    set
    {
        this.Content[i,j]=value;
    }
}
```

Now, I can do `"A[2,3]"`.
As the next step, I also would like to do `"A[2,:]"` (the output will be the 1-dimensional array), how can I implement it?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible as there is no such syntax (as far as I know) in the C# language. Maybe you can use some method (`GetRow(2)` or something like this).

Comment: @SteveB: Post that as an answer.

Comment: Would `A[2]` be appropriate for your use-case?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: this won't allow him to choose between dimension. it's possible to define only one overloads of `this[]` with a single double argument.

Comment: it should not be. The reader of the code could assume that it deals with 1-dim array and result is a number.

Comment: @SteveB: I know, that's why I was asking.

Comment: @MaxLi: It would be obvious from the return type that it would return a one dimensional array. The syntax you wish is simply not supported. You need to think of alternatives. I suggest an explicit variant: `A.Rows[1]` and `A.Columns[1]`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Of course the reader can get it, but it's an extra effort. At first, it looks pretty confusing I think. Besides, think about porting some code from Matlab, NumPy or R that use this syntax.

Comment: @MaxLi: What looks confusing is the syntax you want to achieve. You can't assume that people reading C# code have experience in Matlab.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth The point about Matlab was about porting Matlab code, not about reading. The point of confusion was about using A[2] for access 2-dim array and produce 1-dim array. Then, A.GetRow() as a better option

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's possible as there is no such syntax (as far as I know) in the C# language.

Maybe you can use some method `GetRow(2)` or something like this.

```
public double[] GetRow(int rowNumber)
{
    var result = new double[this.Content.GetLength(0)];
    for(var i=0; i<result.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = this.Content[rowNumber, i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

The same logic for a `GetColumn` should be straightforward.

Comment: thank you for the answer! However, the idea was not to get it done somehow, but to have some syntactic sugar. Strictly saying there's also no need for A[i,j] since A.Content[i,j] does the same, except for sugar.